# ReactJS vs AdobeXD

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, adobe

This is my first time building a web app, and one of the members of my team used Adobe XD to wireframe what the website and what it should look like. It turns out that you can export that to html, css, and some javascript (thousands on thousands of lines of code) but it's missing a lot of it's intended functionality. I was wondering if it'd be better for me to start from scratch with what little React I know and build it from the ground up and copy paste useful stuff over or if I should just try to tweak the code Adobe XD spat out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you should create the React app from scratch and copy paste some markup and styling from generated file. That way it will be easier to think in React way and will break down the app in smaller components and define the data state accordingly.